# Catalyst DBIx::Class No tables found, did you forget to specify db_schema

Tags: perl, catalyst

In Catalyst development, there are so many modulers. When I run the command as follows, I get the error

> No tables found, did you forget to specify db_schema
>
> script/addressbook_create.pl model AddressDB DBIC::Schema AddressBook::Schema::AddressDB create=static dbi:SQLite:/tmp/database

I am reading the book--Catalyst 5.8 the perl MVC framework

My questions:

- How to solve this problem?
- What can I get some helper from perldoc or something else? The doc is much more, and dependencies about modulers is so difficult. What's the key?

Comment: I have created two tables : people and addresses in tmp/database. My DB is sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second reference to AddressDB in your create command there is probably putting the files in a subdirectory below where they should be, ie `lib/AddressBook/Schema/AddressBook/Result/People.pm`. Have a look at your directory structure and compare it to p141 of the book.

I'd suggest you clean that up, and try:

```
script/addressbook_create.pl model AddressDB DBIC::Schema AddressBook::Schema \
  create=static dbi:SQLite:/tmp/database
```